# iphone - Get host name by IP address

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, network-programming, hostname

I have a list of ip addresses in my local wifi network (192.168.1.100-105). How can I get device names? For example "My desktop PC". Application like Fing can do it.

I've found some examples:

[iPhone Tip: No NSHost](http://www.bdunagan.com/2009/11/28/iphone-tip-no-nshost/)

and

[How to get Domain Name of ipAddress and ipAddress from Domain Name in objective-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3572697/how-to-get-domain-name-of-ipaddress-and-ipaddress-from-domain-name-in-objective)

but looks like they works only with addressees from the internet, not from the local network.

Thank you!

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1777449/possible-to-get-the-hostname-of-an-ip-using-systemconfiguration)?

Comment: Thank you! But looks like it works only in mac os, not iOS.

Comment: Hi @user1575129 , did you find what you were looking for? I need the same thing but I can't figure it out yet

Comment: Did you get any success?

Comment: @Bhumit -  Did you found any way?

Comment: Have you succeeded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three main protocols that you can use to get information about devices on your local network: Bonjour, NetBIOS and UPnP. Of these only the first one has build in support in iOS. So you will have to search for libraries or write your own implementation of the other two.

Answer (score 0):

If by device name, you meant UDID (Unique Device Identifier) of the iOS device, its against a proposed US Internet privacy law to access it. If your app tries to get the UDID, it might get rejected from appstore. If you want to track the devices on which your app is running, you can use a few virtual UDID generators like here:[SecureUDID](http://www.secureudid.org)

If you just wanted some unique identifier to identify some device on a network, you might try reading the mac address of the network interface on iDevice. But doing that might/might-not run foul of Apple's guidelines.

Either way, Apple seriously frowns on apps that try to identify user devices (unless they are virtual UDIDs like in the link). So be very sure of what your aim is.

One disclaimer though..if your app is not targeted for sale in USA, accessing UDID is in grey (read unclear) area of Apple's guidelines.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I haven't even mentioned about UDID, I'm looking for name in the network, like "My iPhone"